# UWP - Changing ListViewItem Template on Add

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, datatemplate

I'm having an issue with my code when I try to add a ListViewItem via an observable collection and change it's DataTemplate.

```
            CurrentTicket.Add(new Item { itemID = selectedItem.itemID, price = price, name = selectedItem.name, taxID = selectedItem.taxID,modName = modNames });

        if(modNames.Count() != 0)
        {
            ListViewItem lvi = (ticketListBox).ContainerFromIndex(ticketListBox.Items.Count - 1) as ListViewItem;
            lvi.ContentTemplate = (DataTemplate)this.Resources["CurrentTicketModDataTemplate"];
        }
```

When I run this lvi returns null and the next line fails to execute. Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try breaking that line up a bit so you can see what's going on.  Whats the value of ticketListBox?  What's the value of ticketListBox.Items.Count? Is is the cast to ListViewItem that's failing?  Likely something in there is failing quietly.

Comment: @ErinCarignan I've used this same code in a different situation but the ListViewItem was added in a different event. ticketListBox.Items.Count properly returns the number of ListViewItems in ticketListBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it was undefined is because the it makes more time to create the ListViewItem than it does to add to the observable collection. 
Solution is to wait until it is defined:

```
ListViewItem lvi = ticketListview.ContainerFromItem(item) as ListViewItem;
            while(lvi == null)
            {
                await Task.Delay(25);
                lvi = ticketListview.ContainerFromItem(item) as ListViewItem;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set the DataTemplate and the DataContext.

Like this:

```
ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();

lvi.DataTemplate = ticketListBox.DataTemplate;
lvi.DataContext = YourObservableCollection.Last();
```